# Styling ng-invalid select2 elements

Tags: css, angular, jquery-select2

I need to change `background-color` of a select2 span once it is invalid (and touched).

Here's the template code:

```
      <div class="form-group col-md-2 pull-right">
        <label class="control-label" for="city">City</label>
          <select [disabled]="!properties.get('city').enabled" [(ngModel)]="properties.get('city').value" id="city" name="city" class="select2 form-control" [required]="properties.get('city').initialValue?.length > 0">
            <option *ngFor="let option of properties.get('city').options" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.text}}</option>
          </select>
      </div>
```

Here's the DOM:

[image]

The following CSS styles the element as I desire, but without the condition.

```
:host >>> span.select2-selection{
    background-color: #F1DEDE !important;
}
```

I think that I mainly having trouble understanding how to mix in a Shadow DOM selector with a DOM selector in CSS.
In other words, I want to style a Shadow DOM element (`span.select2-selection`) based on classes given to its' sibling DOM element (`select.ng-invalid.ng-touched`)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so to sum up, there are 3 main problems:

1. The styling classes that I rely on are on the DOM (`<select>`), while the element that I want to style is within their sibling element in the Shadow DOM. AFAIK this is not possible to do with plain CSS - which led me to tackle this issue within the TypeScript.
2. The `<select>` element ng classes are being updated AFTER all of the Select2 events - select2:select, select2:change, change (which means I have to either bind to something else or find another solution)
3. ng-touched is not being updated at all - it remains "ng-untouched" forever, that means that I need to style the element within the first change and not to load it with the styling.

Eventually I came up with this working, ugly solution. I'd love to find something better, but it works with few lines of code:

```
$('.select2').on('change.select2', function (e, data) {
    //Workaround for required fields styling
    let $select2Selection = $(this).next('span').find('.select2-selection'); 
    setTimeout(() => {
        if ($(this).hasClass('ng-invalid')){
            $select2Selection.css('background-color', '#F1DEDE');
        }
        else $select2Selection.css('background-color', '');
        }, 50); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following css

```
  :host >>> .ng-invalid + .select2-selection{
       background-color: #F1DEDE !important;
    }
```

`+` find next sibling which reside in the same parent.

Comment: I know the sibling selector, it doesn't work here. I can't style .select2-selection without using :host. For example, .select2-selection{background-color: #F1DEDE;} doesn't work either.

Comment: Updated the answer and you can see this in action here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sppov1

Comment: Updated the answer and link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sppov1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for changing select2 background-color or color

```js
$('select').select2();

$('.select2').click(function(){
  $('#select2-sel-results')
    .parent()
    .siblings('.select2-search')
    .css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```css
#sel + .select2 .select2-selection__rendered {  background-color: yellow; }

#select2-sel-results { background-color: grey; }

#select2-sel-results .select2-results__option--highlighted { background-color: aqua! important; }

#select2-sel-results .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] { background-color: orange !important; }

.select2-search { background-color: orange; }

.select2-search input { background-color: white; }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <select id="sel" class="select2" style="width:50%">
    <option value="e1" >Element 1</option>
    <option value="e2" >Element 2</option>
    <option value="e3" >Element 3</option>
  </select>
```

Besides you can directly provide css for changes

```
input.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
            background-color:red;
        }
```